# Local SQLite Database in Xamarin Forms

Tags: database, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, connection-string

So I did an example Database **outside** Xamarin Forms using **"DB Browser for SQLite"** and put it in **Assets File**

[image: EXAMPLE DATABASE]

and I'm trying to learn how to connect my Database to it so i did this :

XAML :

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
> <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
>              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
>              xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
>              xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
>              mc:Ignorable="d"
>              x:Class="Behoerdensprache.Pages.FinanzAmt">
>     <ContentPage.Content>
>         <StackLayout>
>             <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
>                 VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
>                 HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
>                    x:Name="LabelControl"/>
>             <Entry Placeholder="Search" x:Name="SearchEntry"/>
>             <Button Text="Press me" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
>         </StackLayout>
>     </ContentPage.Content>
> </ContentPage>
> ```

C# ButtonCode :

```
    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DataBaseLocation);
        conn.CreateTable<Wortschatz>();
        var gets = conn.Table<Wortschatz>().Where(i => i.Wort == SearchEntry.Text).ToString();
        LabelControl.Text = gets;

        conn.Close();

    }
```

**App.DataBaseLocation** is defined in the Mainactivity and AppDelegate :

in Mainactivity :

```
        string dbName = "BeamtenSprache.sqlite";
        string folderPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        string fullPath = Path.Combine(folderPath, dbName);
        LoadApplication(new App(fullPath));
```

in AppDelegate :

```
        string dbName = "wortschatz.sqlite";
        string folderPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "..", "Library");
        string fullPath = Path.Combine(folderPath, dbName);
        LoadApplication(new App(fullPath));
```

**new App(fullPath)** this part i defined in App.cs :

```
 public static string DataBaseLocation = string.Empty;
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    }

    public App(string databaseLocation)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
        DataBaseLocation = databaseLocation;
    }
```

but when i run the app and i press the Button this shows :

[image: ON_ANDROID]

Comment: What do you expect it to display?

Comment: If i write something like "Auto" in the Entry it should Change the label Text to the Row in the Database where Wort == Auto .. i mean this is what I'm trying to do .. but I'm doing it all wrong somehow ! @Jason

Comment: you are calling ToString() on the query, not the result.  What if your query returns more than one row?  And how do you intent do display an entire row of data in a single label?  I'd suggest calling ToList() on the result and storing it in a variable.  Then check if it has at least one result, then extract the row and column you want to display and update the Label

Comment: I did what you said and it didn't work either .. i thing the problem is that my app can't find the Database or is seeing the Database empty ..! is there something i must do to let the app read the database from the Assets File ?! @Jason

Comment: if it's in Assets, you probably need to copy it to an app folder first

Comment: using (var br = new BinaryReader(Application.Current.Assets.Open("people.db3"))) .. it giving me here an error on Assets that Application doesn't contain Assets ! NO SOLUTION FOUND YET .. and i tried too many Methods nothing works for me .. i know the problem is from me but i can't find it .. i can't figure it out .. anyway thx a lot @Jason

Comment: You need to do it in the Android project.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/android-assets?tabs=windows

Answer (score 0):

There is an [Todo](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Todo) sample project in xamarin.forms.samples shows how to store and access data in a local SQLite database.

In **Android** project, he put the `db file` in [Todo/Todo.Android/Resources/raw/](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Todo/Todo.Android/Resources/raw)

In **iOS** project, he put the `db file` in [Todo/Todo.iOS/Resources/](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Todo/Todo.iOS/Resources)

And then he get the `db path` by:

```
public static class Constants
{
    public const string DatabaseFilename = "TodoSQLite.db3";

    public static string DatabasePath
    {
        get
        {
            var basePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
            return Path.Combine(basePath, DatabaseFilename);
        }
    }
}
```

You can download it and try with the code there in your project. For more information, you can read the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases).

If you can't solve the problem, you can share your project here and I will check it:).